# The right syntax to use near 'Name= ?'

Tags: go

i'm trying to filter my registers with a "Name" parameter.

I make this handler function:

```
func GetFuncionaries(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var f model.Funcionary
    var t util.App
    var d db.DB
    err := d.Connection()
    db := d.DB
    defer db.Close()

    Id, _ := strconv.Atoi(r.FormValue("Id"))
    Name:= r.FormValue("Name")

    f.Id = int64(Id)
    f.Name = Name

    funcionaries, err := f.GetFuncionaries(db)
    if err != nil {
            log.Printf("[handler/GetFuncionaries-  Error: %s", err.Error())
            t.ResponseWithError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error(), "")
        }
        return
    }
    t.ResponseWithJSON(w, http.StatusOK, funcionaries, 0, 0)
}
```

And the function model:

```
func (f *Funcionary) GetFuncionaries(db *sql.DB) ([]Funcionary, error) {
    var values []interface{}
    var where []string

    if f.Name != "" {
        where = append(where, "Name= ?")
        values = append(values, f.Name)
    }


    rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT Id, Data, Role, Name
                    FROM funcionaries
                    WHERE 1=1 `+strings.Join(where, " AND "), values...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    funcionaries:= []Funcionary{}
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        var funcionary Funcionary
        if err = rows.Scan(&funcionario.Id, &funcionario.Name, &Others...); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        funcionaries = append(funcionaries, funcionary)
    }
    return funcionaries, nil
}
```

But when i make a call in postman like:

http://localhost:8000/api/funcionaries?Name=a

I receive the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Name= ?' at line 3",

I'm forgetting something?

Comment: This code is prone to [SQL injection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should take extreme precautions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like the SQL string produced by your code will be

```sql
SELECT Id, Data, Role, Name FROM funcionaries WHERE 1=1 Name= ?
```

Whereas what you want is:

```sql
SELECT Id, Data, Role, Name FROM funcionaries WHERE 1=1 AND Name= ?
```

To do this you could modify your code like so:

```golang
q := `SELECT Id, Data, Role, Name
          FROM funcionaries
          WHERE True`
if len(where) != 0 {
    q = q + " AND " + strings.Join(where, " AND ")
}
rows, err := db.Query(q, values...)
```